# PHP replacing double-quotes with single-quotes when parsing is not required across entire application

Tags: php, performance, parsing, php-5.3

If I have many references such as this code snippet below throughout my application, where I am using double-quotes instead of single-quotes/apostrophes when there is no parsing required would replacing all of these double-quotes with single-quotes has a positive effect on the performance of my application?

```
$is_parkland = $info["is_parkland"];
```

I understand that using the `"` in the example above is asking PHP to parse the contents between the double-quotes. This sort of thing is apparent across my application in legacy code.

I have around 300,000 lines of PHP in my application and, really, i'm interested to know if they were *all* replaced, as necessary, would this have a noticable or positive effect on my application?

Is it worth the effort? I am using PHP 5.3.13.

Comment: As of 5.3, the compiler emits the same opcode sequences to the RTS. So for PHP 5.3.13, it is pretty much a waste of time -- you're more likely to make some funny edit cock-up and break working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP Benchmarks:

http://phpbench.com/

It looks like with newer versions of PHP there is little difference between single and double quotes.

Comment: This is not true, see the comments on dynamic's post

Comment: Which part of it is not true? Looking at the PHP benchmarks page, the difference between the two is small. In fact, if you reload the page a few times, you can see that it changes which is fastest. From those benchmarks it is impossible to tell if one is faster. Or as I said originally, there is little difference. Admittedly TerryE's comment is more detailed showing that there is **no** difference, but I don't see how I was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the performance difference is not significant.
Also, if the application performance is satisfactory and load is not high, then the gain will be unnoticed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes have a higher speed than double quotes. It's not much, but with 300k lines of code it may have a significant effect.
Source: [PHP Benchmark](http://phpbench.com/)

Comment: The benchmarks from that side do not show a performance gain of one type over the other.

Comment: `+ 103 %single (') quotes. 20 bytes Text and 3x a $ : $tmp[] = 'aa $ aaaa $ aaaa $ a';Total time: 194 µs view code`
`+ 105 %double (") quotes. 20 bytes Text and 3x a $ : $tmp[] = "aa $ aaaa $ aaaa $ a";Total time: 197 µs view code`
And still... those 3µs probably still fall in the 99% confidence interval for statistical analysis.

Comment: If you use VLD to disassemble comparison code, then you will see that from PHP 5.3, it makes no difference **at all**.  The compiler phase treats them as exactly the same and generates the same code if the string doesn't contain escaped variables, etc..